Ubuntu 22.04 kernel 6.8.0-40 on Lenovo V130-15IKB fails managing nvme
After updating to 6.8.0-40, my Lenovo V130-15IKB fails to boot with a
"nvme failed with error -12" message in dmesg.

Booting on older 6.5.0-45 goes flawlessly.
Is there a driver problem on 6.8.40, will it be addressed, or should I stick to 6.5?
Thank you very much,
